# Configure Spark 3 thrift server with Apache Ranger

Tags: apache-ranger, spark-thriftserver, apache-spark-3.0

I am trying to configure Spark 3.3.0 Thrift Server with Apache Ranger but I cannot find any resources or information for this setup.Any suggestions on how to implement this? Thanks very much!

I already have an STS (kerberos jdbc) turned on and Apache Ranger on a Kerberos authenticated cluster, but I don't know how to integrate STS with Apache Ranger. I have done my research on https://github.com/yaooqinn/spark-ranger, but It's an archived repository and the code doesn't support Spark 3.3.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found the new plugin:

https://kyuubi.readthedocs.io/en/master/security/authorization/spark/install.html
it's working with apache spark 3.x thrift server